# VS 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova - iOS Remote Build not using buildServer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to get iOS remotebuild working for my Tools for Apache Cordova project. From what I can tell it's still trying to build using my local windows machine.

I get these errors:

Warning     Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.  [AppName]   C:\dev[AppName]\MDAVSCLI   1

Error       C:\Users\James.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-ios\3.7.0\package\bin\create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT    [AppName]   C:\dev[AppName]\MDAVSCLI   1

The output windows shows: 
buildServerUrl: https://192.168.1.77:3000/cordova
buildTarget: iOSEmulatoriPhone5

and it successfully connects to the remotebuild server when I set up the RemoteAgentConfiguration in Options. I see the GET request in the mac terminal for that, but nothing when I run the build (tried both the simulator and the remote device option).

I'm running vs2015 and ran the latest updates for Tools for Apache Cordova.

Comment: What version of Cordova are you targeting?

Comment: Was on 4.2.0, I'll update to the latest and give it a shot.

Comment: Yep that's the problem. Even upgrading to 4.3 should fix it.

Comment: That did it, feel free to add it as an answer so I can mark it correct. Thank you!

Comment: How could i find the current installed version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you are targeting an older version of Cordova. Remote build requires a later version of the iOS platform that's pinned to 4.2. The earliest version that remote build supports is 4.3.